# How do I check the amount of times each array object appears in a string, and then save that into a seperate array?

Tags: php, arrays

Basically what I am trying to do here is get a text input (a paragraph), and then save each word into an array.  Then I want to check each word in the array against the original paragraph to see how many times it occurred.  By doing this I am hopefully going to be able to check what the topic is.  Originally I started this is as an open ended school project, but I am more interested in finding out how to do this for my own sanity.
Here is my code (this is after I requested the text input in html code above):

```
$paragraph = $_POST['text'];
$paragraph = str_replace('   ',' ',$paragraph);
$paragraph = str_replace('  ',' ',$paragraph);
$paragraph = strtolower($paragraph);
$words = explode(" ",$paragraph);
$count = count($words);
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    echo $words[$x];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

So far I have been able to get the words all lowercase and to replace all the extra spaces in my text, and then subsequently save that to an array.  For now I am just displaying the words.

This is where I have run into some problems.  I was thinking I could have a multidimensional array where it would be something along the lines of

```
$words[1]["word"][0]["amount"];
```

The word would be the actual word in the paragraph, and amount would count how many times it showed up in the paragraph.  If anyone has basic concepts for doing this, or there is something I am missing here I would appreciate your help.  The main thing I need help with is checking the amount of times each word shows up in the paragraph.  I couldn't get this to work (it was within the prior for loop):

```
substr_count($words[$x],$paragraph)
```

To recap, I am trying to take a paragraph, save each different word into an array (I have managed to do this successfully) and then save the amount of times the word shows up in the paragraph into a different array (or a multidimensional array).  Once I get this data I am going to see which words I used the most, while filtering out filler words like "the" and "a".

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using `preg_replace('/\W+/', ' ', $paragraph);` and simplifying the rest of your code to this:

```
$paragraph = preg_replace('/\W+/', ' ', $paragraph);
$filter = array('the', 'a');
$words = explode(' ',$paragraph);
$countWords = array();
foreach($words as $w)
{
    if(trim($w) != "" && array_search($w, $filter) === false)
    {
        if(!isset($countWords[$w]))
            $countWords[$w] = 0;

        $countWords[$w] += 1;
    }
}
```

This will give you how many times each word is used. And if you don't care about case, then you can use `$countWords[strtolower($w)]` instead. Also, with the `$filter` array I added, you can add whatever words that you don't want to count in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  My inexperience with php makes it difficult to simplify code into concise statements like this.  This looks like it will for me

Comment: @gshr11 No problem. If you need any help understanding the code I have here let me know and I can add more details.

Comment: One question I have is with the parameters inside the preg_replace, what exactly is /\w{2,}/ replacing?

Comment: `/\w{2,}/` replaces any whitespace of 2 or more in a row.

Comment: I'm getting an undefined index error on the line you have countWords[$w] +=1;

Comment: Check out my updated answer. That should fix the error you are getting.

Comment: The only error I'm getting now is "undefined $countWords" on the line below the isset

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. I accidentally used `\w` instead of `\W` which matches the opposite of what you wanted... Oops. And I changed `{2,}` to just a `+` to remove everything that's not a word. I also forgot a  parenthesis in the `if` I added. It should all be working now.